# Codeigniter anchorlink in elseif statement

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I got an elseif loop for status statements in my code. But now I want to make a div link with an id. Let me post the code I got now:

```
elseif($company['status'] == 2)
{ 
    echo "<p>Afspraak geplanned</p><p>"
    anchor('company/individual/'.$company['id'], 
         '<div class='maakqsaan'>Maak een quickscan</div>');
    "</p>";
}
```

And maybe as you can guess this isn't working...Could someone please help me?

Comment: Uhm not to get into an fight, but when i posted that i couldn't accept the answer. (downtime) and now i get back i did accept it (as i intended to do in the first place!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is the incorrect use of quotes and concatenation (you can even see it in how the markup is colored in the code area. Doesn't your IDE of choice highlight invalid php? Just asking, it would help you a lot). Try this:

```
 elseif($company['status'] == 2)
 { 
    echo "<p>Afspraak geplanned</p><p>". anchor("company/individual/".$company['id'], "<div class='maakqsaan'>Maak een quickscan</div>")."</p>";
 }
```

Comment: Well i made it an div because its an button which isn't used everywhere else. Thats why i choose for this way. But your answer did work, thanks alot!